# Can we integrate a measurable function defined on a conull subset of a complete measure space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a complete measure space, and suppose $f$ is a measurable function with domain of $f$ the set $X \setminus N$ for a measurable set $N$ of measure $0$.

Does it make sense to talk about $\int \limits_{X} f \mathrm{d}\mu$?  I've heard varying opinions on this and I really need a definitive answer.

Here is my idea to answer this question:  Yes, it makes sense to talk about integrating $f$ over the set $X$ even if it is only defined on a smaller set, because we can find a function $g$ (is it necessarily measurable?) such that $f = g$ if $x \not \in N$, that is, $f = g$ a.e. d$\mu$.  Then, we can define $\int \limits_{X} f \mathrm{d}\mu$ as $\int \limits_{X} g \mathrm{d}\mu$.

But then I am conflicted, because this does not agree with the definition of Lebesgue integral, which is $\int \limits_{X} f \mathrm{d}\mu = \sup \{ \int \limits_{X} s \mathrm{d}\mu \mid 0 \leq s \leq f \text{ and $s$ is simple} \}$ (assuming that $f$ is a non-negative funciton).  We can't find simple functions between $0$ and $f$ on the set $N$...

Please help me put my mind at ease.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense to define

$$\int_X f\,d\mu := \int_X g\,d\mu$$

where $g$ is an extension of $f$ to $X$. For a complete measure space, any extension of $f$ is measurable, since every subset of the null set $N$ is measurable. If the measure space is not complete, you can extend $f$ by setting the value of the extension to $0$ on $N$ to obtain a measurable extension. Since $N$ is a null set, the value

$$\int_X g\,d\mu$$

is the same for **all** measurable extensions $g$ of $f$.

That is standard procedure.

Comment: Why would setting the extension equal to $0$ on the set of measure $0$ make it measurable in a non-complete measure space?

Comment: Because then the preimage of every measurable subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ (or $[-\infty,+\infty]$, if the function may attain the values $\pm \infty$) is either a measurable subset $M$ of $X\setminus N$, or $M\cup N$, where $M$ is a measurable subset of $X\setminus N$, depending on whether $0\in A$ or not. In both cases, the preimage is a measurable subset of $X$.